# Get Selected Value of Area Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having problems writing a simple directive that updates d3 area chart  using angularjs.

**[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L41p61w9/12/)**

This is the model:

```
app.controller('chartController', ['$scope' , 'chartService', function ($scope, chartService) {

    $scope.data = chartService;
}]);
```

When I select range using sub chart, I want to get values of selected date in label or input.

Comment: Where's the function that updates `$scope.data`?

Answer (score -1):

following code worked for me.

```
brush.extent()
```

May be it help someone